# Illustrator - Spray Symbol around shape

Tags: adobe-illustrator

i'm trying to achieve something similar to this in illustrator

[image]

- How can i spray a symbol around a shape
- How can i spray within my symbol (just like the example in the image)

Comment: I would only know to do that manually. The only other option that comes to mind is scripting. Looking at the edge of the infinity symbol and how the dots follow the shape from then on, I wouldn't be surprised if they did it by first applying a dotted stroke to the symbol, then expanded and misaligned them a bit and continued to manually add dots around the symbol.

Comment: I tried to do it manually, but it takes sooo much time

Answer (score 4):

If your in a hurry and need this today then use something called rejection sampling. Idea is to have any number of random samples and then reject the ones that do not fall into your criteria. Here's how you could approach this.

1. Make a random field

   [image]
2. make logo

   [image]
3. make logo transparent and run transparency flattener

   [image]
4. subtract and eliminate all paths with more then 4 points.

[image]

Now the effect does work better if you have a pattern on the edge of the logo. Like in your example so store the logo path and subtract slightly offset version. and add a scatter stroked edge that has same symbol for more definition.

[image]

**Final Image**: The result after some manual tweaking for a few seconds and a ring of edge points done with a scatter brush.

This is also pretty easy to script.

Comment: wow, never thought of that! i will try it now. thank you!

Comment: Do you have any links to a video tutorial or smth? I'm having difficulties with steps 3-4

Comment: @user2093301 No, i did this just now took me about 20 minutes to do this and write the document (no i hadn't done this before). But would have been faster if i wouldn't have had to experiment. In 20:20 hindsight you could just do the deletion with pathfinder. I did the selection with a script but its pretty quick to do manually once the bulk of the problems have been eliminated.

Comment: i know that you can define it from Edit -> Transparency Flattener Presets, but how do you run it

Comment: @user2093301 **Object  -> Flatten Transparency**

Comment: got it! now how do you eliminate all paths with more then 4 points?

Answer (score 0):

Please use simple strokes of the same shapes but with dotted lines (alternative stroke shapes in the strokes panel). Very simple. Later on, you can provide them the gradient.